# i'm implementing jeuclid library, my code works as an application but not as a servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, tinymce

**this thing works**

```
public class Convert{       
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{
Converter converter = Converter.getInstance();;        
converter.convert(new File("F:/outputxml.txt"),new File("F:/outBIGB.jpg"),"image/jpeg");
}
}
```

***but this doesnt..***

```
   protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)throws ServletException, IOException 
   {           
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        Converter converter = Converter.getInstance();
        converter.convert(new File("F:/outputxml.txt"),new File("F:/outBIGB.jpg"), "image/jpeg");
}
```

***it creates the jpg file but that remains empty***

and when i try to open than image using picasa or photo viewer it says "invalid image"

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Where does it say invalid image? Your question is missing important details and context information.

Comment: Format your code, format your question.